# Migrating from RxJS4 to RxJS5 - implementing an Observer

Tags: javascript, node.js, rxjs, rxjs5

In one of my projects, I have the following code, and upon migrating to RxJS5, Rx.Observer seems to no longer be defined:

```
let index = 0;

let obsEnqueue = this.obsEnqueue = new Rx.Subject();

this.queueStream = Rx.Observable.create(obs => {
    var push = Rx.Observer.create(v => {             // ! error
        if ((index % obsEnqueue.observers.length) === obsEnqueue.observers.indexOf(push)) {
            obs.next(v);
        }
    });
    return obsEnqueue.subscribe(push);
});

this.push = (v) => {
    obsEnqueue.next(v);
    index++;
};
```

this no longer works because `Rx.Observer` is not defined

in the migration guide:

https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md

it says:

> Observer is an interface now

However, that shouldn't meant that Rx.Observer, even if it's an interface, shouldn't have a "static" method, called create.

Anyway, `Rx.Observer` doesn't seem to exist anymore.
I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined
```

How can I create an Observer somehow yielding similar results to my code above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the source:

```
export interface Observer<T> {
  closed?: boolean;
  next: (value: T) => void;
  error: (err: any) => void;
  complete: () => void;
}
```

`Observer<T>` is an interface with the `onNext`, `onCompleted` and `onError` method. An interface is only a language construct. It is merely used by the typescript compiler to type-check objects requiring an `Observer<T>`. It is erased on compilation.

The class `Subscriber<T>` implements the interface `Observer<T>`.
It means that `Subscriber<T>` is the actual concrete class with the above methods.

So you use `var push = Rx.Subscriber.create(v => {  [...]` instead.

Note:

In the original Rx implementation, the interfaces were `IObservable<T>` and `IObserver<T>` and used extension methods to allow composition. When it came to JS, they had to have methods on the prototype of `Observable` / `Observer` itself to enable composition - so the class itself had the methods.

Comment: do you think the code could be simplified in the way that Mark is getting at?

Comment: No, you need the direct reference to be observer.

Comment: in the code that you gave me, I am trying to figure out what the difference is between using this.queueStream vs. this.obsEnqueue, would it result in the same thing or not? Why? Please lmk thanks!

Comment: Here is a related question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41499889/unsubscribe-function-callback-hook-in-observable-executor-function

Comment: `queueStream` is the actual observable you want to hand out. `obsEnqueue` is the subject you push items into, so that it can keep a track of all the subsriptions without you having to.

Comment: Do you use Skype or something? This sort of async format isn't working.

Comment: yeah actually, I got what you mean now, so don't worry, yeah I have skype, but ghangouts is easier - alexander.d.mills@gmail.com

Answer (score 2):

To be honest I don't understand what you code does but even though `Observer` class doesn't exist any more it was mostly replaced by `Subscriber` class that is used in almost the same way as `Observer`.

It has a static `Subscriber.create` method. See https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/Subscriber.ts#L32

This method returns a `Subscriber` object that you can later use such as `obsEnqueue.subscribe(push);`.

Comment: LOL I actually don't know how it works either, I stole it from someone else, and it does work, I just don't know how :) I think there would be a way to simplify it and Mark is getting at that

Answer (score 1):

Why not just inline the onNext function directly into the subscribe?

```
this.queueStream = Rx.Observable.create(obs => {
    return obsEnqueue.subscribe(
      v => {
        if ((index % obsEnqueue.observers.length) === obsEnqueue.observers.indexOf(push)) {
            obs.next(v);
        }
      }
    );
});
```

Comment: the push variable is not defined in your case, looks like we need a handle on that

Answer (score 1):

If I understood what this partial code is trying to do ...
I think No,
I don't see how you can make this "simpler".
perhaps what is there to be improved
is to make it more "reusable",
make it a module ?,
or perhaps a Rx operator if there isn't one like yet...

this could be an attempt to it

```
/*
    "dependencies": {
        "rxjs": "^5.0.2"
    }
*/

import {Observable, Observer, Subject, Subscriber} from "rxjs";

export interface ICircularQueue<T> extends Observable<T> {
    push(value: T): void;
}

/**
* on every push use 'NEXT' observer/subscription,
* in the order they've been subscribed,
* cycling back to 1st subscription after last
*/
export function create<T>(): ICircularQueue<T> {

    let index = 0;

    let obsEnqueue = new Subject<T>();

    let queueStream = Observable.create((obs: Observer<T>) => {

        let push = Subscriber.create<T>(v => {
            // ! error ?
            if ((index % obsEnqueue.observers.length) === obsEnqueue.observers.indexOf(push)) {
                obs.next(v);
            }
        });

        return obsEnqueue.subscribe(push);
    });

    queueStream.push = (v: T) => {
        obsEnqueue.next(v);
        index++;
    };

    return queueStream;
}
```

then a basic test ....

```
import * as CircularQueue from "./CircularQueue";
import * as assert from "assert";

const $in = (array: any[], x: any) => {
    for (let $x of array) {
        if ($x === x) { return true; }
    }
    return false;
};

describe("CircularQueue", () => {

    it("works", () => {
        let queue = CircularQueue.create();

        let result: number[] = [];
        queue.subscribe(x => {
            assert.ok($in([0, 4, 8], x));
            result.push(0);
        });
        queue.subscribe(x => {
            assert.ok($in([1, 5, 9], x));
            result.push(1);
        });
        queue.subscribe(x => {
            assert.ok($in([2, 6, 10], x));
            result.push(2);
        });
        queue.subscribe(x => {
            assert.ok($in([3, 7, 11], x));
            result.push(3);
        });

        for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            queue.push(i);
        }

        assert.equal(result.join(), "0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3");
    });
});
```