# "Unsubscribe" function callback/hook in Observable "executor" function

Tags: javascript, rxjs5

I am confused about what the purpose of the "dispose" or "unsubscribe" function is for, which is (optionally) returned from an observable "executor" function, like so:

```
const Rx = require('rxjs');

const obs = Rx.Observable.create(obs => {

    // we are in the Observable "executor" function
    obs.next(4);

     // we return this function, which gets called if we unsubscribe
    return function () {
        console.log('disposed');
    }

});

    const s1 = obs.subscribe(
        function (v) {
            console.log(v);
        },
        function (e) {
            console.log(e);
        },
        function () {
            console.log('complete');
        }
    );

    const s2 = obs.subscribe(
        function (v) {
            console.log(v);
        },
        function (e) {
            console.log(e);
        },
        function () {
            console.log('complete');
        }
    );


    s1.unsubscribe();
    s2.unsubscribe();
```

What confuses me is that such a function would actually be more likely to hold on to references in your code and therefore prevent garbage collection.

Can anyone tell me what the purpose is of returning a function in that scenario, what the function is called, and what it's signature is? I am having trouble figuring out information about it.

I also see much more complex examples of returning a subscription from the executor function, for example this:

```
    let index = 0;

    let obsEnqueue = this.obsEnqueue = new Rx.Subject();

    this.queueStream = Rx.Observable.create(obs => {

        const push = Rx.Subscriber.create(v => {
            if ((index % obsEnqueue.observers.length) === obsEnqueue.observers.indexOf(push)) {
                obs.next(v);
            }
        });

        return obsEnqueue.subscribe(push);
    });
```

This seems to return a subscription instead of just a plain function. Can anyone explain what's going on with this?

To make it a clear question, what is the difference between doing this:

```
const sub = new Rx.Subject();

const obs = Rx.Observable.create($obs => {

    $obs.next(4);
    return sub.subscribe($obs);

});
```

and not returning the result of the subscribe call:

```
const sub = new Rx.Subject();

const obs = Rx.Observable.create($obs => {

    $obs.next(4);
    sub.subscribe($obs);

});
```

Comment: I am not sure if it's actually called an "executor" function, but that's the name of the analogue in the Promises world

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `unsubscribe` function that `Rx.Observable.create` needs to return is invoked when downstream does not listen to the stream anymore, effectively giving you time to clean up resources.

In regards to your question; `.subscribe()` returns the subscription on which you can call `.unsubscribe()`. So if you want to do something with an other subscription you can pipe through that subscription to your downstream:

```js
    const obs = Rx.Observable.create($obs => {
      const timer = Rx.Observable.interval(300)
        .do(i => console.log('emission: ' + i))

      return timer.subscribe($obs);
    });
    obs.take(4).subscribe(i => console.log('outer-emission:'+i))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.0.2/Rx.js"></script>
```

Without the unsubscribe function you would stop listening to the observable but the interval created internally would keep on running:

```js
const obs = Rx.Observable.create($obs => {
  const timer = Rx.Observable.interval(300)
    .do(i => console.log('emission: ' + i))
    .take(10)
    .subscribe(
      val => $obs.next(val),
      err => $obs.error(err),
      () => $obs.complete()
    );

  return function(){} // empty unsubscribe function, internal subscription will keep on running
});
obs.take(4).subscribe(i => console.log('outer-emission:'+i))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.0.2/Rx.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks! In your first code block, if I don't return timer, but leave everything the same, then things work as expected (there seems to be no difference whether I return timer.do or just call timer.do, so not sure if your explanation is 100% correct? It seems that not returning the timer.do call is ok (in the first example)? Regarding second example, I do see that emission keeps get logged even after 4 takes.

Comment: But in the first example if we don't return timer.do things still work! I don't get it.

Comment: Hi Olegzandr, in the first example i have chained the operators. So it is not returning the timer but the subscribe() on the timer. I have updated the example to make this more clear. Without returning the subscribe is effectively the same as the second example.